# How to Load a view Codeigniter using post and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
$(".booking_hotel").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",   
        url: base_url + 'hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking',   
        data: id
    });
});
```

Function in my controller is like this :

```
function hotel_booking()
{   
    $data = $this->input->post();      

    $data = array(
        'hotel_request' => $data,
    );   

    $this->load->view('hotel_booking/booking_hotel_view',$data);
}
```

It not successful to load view. But in console firebug(tab html), the view could appear.

How to load view booking_hotel_view when class .booking_hotel clicked?

Thank you

Comment: so only you need redirect to `hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking` when `.booking_hotel` clicked? why using ajax?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, Yes. I use ajax to send parameters use post method. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The view from `ajax` comes to you as `ajax` response. You have to put it in your desired place.

Let you have div with `id="my_div"` and you want to show your view in this `div`. So your code will be

```
$(".booking_hotel").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",   
        url: base_url + 'hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking',   
        data: id
    }).done(function(response){
       $('#my_div').html(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Whether it can send parameter using post without using ajax?
Because I want to be when the page loads, it will reload the page. If using ajax, it not reload the page

Comment: @mosestoh The above rectified code will do the magic as you are desired. If you want to post the data, you can send form data to the method in controller by echoing `form_open('controller/method');`. Else, you can send the data through ajax. As you said above, posting form data will refresh the page, whereas, posting data from ajax, wont refresh. What you want to do with the data now?

Comment: @Md. Sahadat Hossain, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458436/why-call-session-not-working-codeigniter-3

Answer (score 0):

try this. It will reload/redirect to you `hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking`. i.e load your `booking_hotel_view`

```
  $(".booking_hotel").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",   
        url: base_url + 'hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking',   
        data: id
    }).done(function(response){
       window.location.href = "hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking";
    });
});
```

As you doing nothing with your ajax post data you may use as

```
$(".booking_hotel").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "hotel_booking/hotel/hotel_booking";
    });
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458436/why-call-session-not-working-codeigniter-3