# Why call session not working? (codeigniter 3)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

my config is like this :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';  // select database driver
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

My autoload is like this :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'functions');
```

In controller **login.php** :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('club', 'chelsea');
```

In controller **dashboard.php** :

```
echo $this->session->userdata('club');
```

It did not succeed in calling the session club if different controller

But, when I call session club in the same controller(controller **login.php**), it's working

I try `$this->library->load('session');` in the constructor of `Dashboard.php`. But it's not success

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: did you load session in autoload.php file??

Comment: @Mohit Jain, Yes, I  load session in autoload.php file. But it's not working

Comment: have you recive any error when `var_dump($this->session->userdata('club'))` in Dashboard???
I am not seeing `$config['sess_driver']` params in your config

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, The result : NULL. I had add `$config['sess_driver']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the answer from @Ali suggests will work or load the session library in the constructor of `Dashboard.php` like so...

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
  }

  //the rest of controller's code
}
```

Or if you only need sessions in one particular function inside the controller load the library in that function instead.

The point is that the library has to be loaded somewhere before you can make calls to its functions.

The choice of autoloading or explicitly loading session in a controller might depend on how often your site needs to use sessions. If every controller uses them then chose autoload. If sessions are needed in only a few places then it is a waste of resources to load them where they are not used.

Comment: I try `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'functions');` in autuload and I try `$this->library->load('session');` in the constructor of `Dashboard.php`. It's not working

Comment: Maybe a cookie setting problem? Edit your question and add config settings for cookie_domain, cookie_path, and cookie_secure.

Comment: Thank you.  I change setting like this : `$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;`. It's working

Comment: Hey @DFriend, kinda late, but it's `$this->load->library('session')`, not the way you have written it in the code.

Answer (score 37):

In CodeIgniter 3.x if you just upgraded to PHP version 7.x, go to `system/libraries/Session/session.php` at line 281 and replace :

```
ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);
```

by :

```
ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);
```

Comment: why this solution works? i don't understand mechanism. isn't there any solution without touch system folder?

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem , then I check the code in Session.php and find that :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
        && (
            !is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            OR !preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]))
){
    unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);
}
```

but the cookie is only 32 length ,so 'ci' create a new cookie  everytime.

I change

```
  OR !preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
```

to

```
  OR !preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
```

then everything is ok !

Answer (score 1):

For working session, It is important to set encryption key in config file. You can set any keywords as encryption key. Use difficult strings it improve session security. An example given below
$config['encryption_key'] = '4n9*^%%$3n^&4v&%7@!90&$$3c3x$^*$m8a456#@tgf%$$c';

Answer (score 0):

You need to load session library by default using `application/config/autoload.php`

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I had  load session in autoload.php file. But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest version of CI 3.0.6, and when i compare the session part in the path application/config/config.php you have

```
$config['sess_driver']          = 'database';  // select database driver
$config['sess_save_path']       = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

and the original file has (with your info)

```
$config['sess_driver']             = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']         = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path']          = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip']           = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

After that you are right in the autoload file
application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'functions');
```

Then in one controller whe make this

```
class Example extends CI_Controlelr{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        if( $this->session->has_userdata('test_name')){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('exist_userdata', 'The session was seted before');

            redirect(base_url('index.php/example2'), 'refresh');
        }
        else{
            $newdata = array(
                                'test_name' => 'name',
                                'test_id'   => 12
                            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('set_userdata_ok', 'You set your user data');

            redirect(base_url('index.php/example2'), 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

applicationi/controller/Example2.php

```
class Example2 extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('example/index');
    }
}
```

application/views/example/index.php

```
<div>
    <?php
        if( isset( $this->session->flashdata('set_userdata_ok'))){
            echo $this->session->flashdata('set_userdata_ok');
        }
        if( isset( $this->session->flashdata(exist_userdata))){
            echo $this->session->flashdata('exist_userdata');
        }
    ?>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <?php
        echo "printing general";
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo "<hr>";
        var_dump($this->session->userdata());
        echo "<hr><hr>";
        echo "printing spesific data";
        echo $_SESSION['test_name'];
        echo $this->session->test_name;
        echo "<hr>";
        echo $this->session->userdata('test_name');
    ?>
</div>
```

Hope this can helpyou debugging the session library, if you have more problems, sen the result in every echo i make in view

Answer (score 0):

By default codeigniter 3 uses file drivers, so you should to create a directory like:

```
mkdir /<path to your application directory>/sessions/
chmod 0700 /<path to your application directory>/sessions/
chown www-data /<path to your application directory>/sessions/
```

[Codeigniter info](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#using-the-session-class)

Before, you should to update config.php with path directory:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'sessions';
```

Bonus: If you are using macOSX you should look what it your apache user:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
[...]
User _www <-----
Group _www <----
[...]
```